# Filter request JPQL (Find entries that do not contain an element with a specific id in the list)

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpql

Good afternoon, I’m trying to make the right query for data sampling, but apparently I don’t know something ((

I need to display users who are not contained in the teams for the project with the given id

My request partially works: it filters users, but if the user is in another command of another project, then the condition is not satisfied ((

```
@Query("select distinct u from User u " +
        "left join u.userTeams uTeams " +
        "where u.userTeams is empty or uTeams.teamProject.projectId <> :projectId")
List<User> findAllNotAddedToProject(@Param("projectId") Long project);
```

The screenshot shows that the user has two teams with different projects, so I need to not find this user, because one of the teams is assigned to the project, and the second is not (the request finds it by the second command)

[image]

My data base schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following

```
@Query("select u from User u where not exists (" +
        "select 1 from Team t join t.users sub " +
        "where sub.id = u.id empty and t.teamProject.projectId = :projectId)")
List<User> findAllNotAddedToProject(@Param("projectId") Long project);
```